# How can I print something only when cck field has certain value on node.tpl.php?

Tags: 6, entities, theming

I need to print something conditionally in my `node.tpl.php` depending on the cck value of a field on my content type.

For example, if `field_color` has "*red*" or "*blue*", then print "*It has color*" and if it has other values print empty text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
if (isset($node->field_color[0]['value'])) {
  //If you want the field value to be displayed      
  print $node->field_color[0]['value'];
  //If you want some custom text to be displayed
  print 'It has colour';
} 
else {
  print 'Empty Text';
}
```

Or with ternary operators:

```
print (!empty($node->field_color[0]['value']) ? $node->field_color[0]['value'] : 'Empty text';
```

You'll probably either want to put in some logic to make sure the field exists though, or create a `node-TYPE.tpl.php` for your specific content type.

**EDIT**

This should sort out your red or blue issue:

```
if (isset($node->field_color[0]['value'])) {

  $colour_value = $node->field_color[0]['value'];

  if ($colour_value == 'red' || $colour_value == 'blue') {
    $colour = $colour_value;
  }
}

print (isset($colour)) ? $colour : t('Empty Text');
```

I've only put the field value into a variable to save space - you don't have to do this if you don't want to :-)

Comment: Go with the first one...the second one's over 80 characters :P

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to narrow down the condition of value to only "red" or "blue" and print "Empty Text" for the rest of the color (other than "red" or "blue").

Comment: I've edited my answer.  If the colour is user input, you might also want to run `$colour` through `check_plain` before outputting it!